# Entity Framework Core - binding SP return value to project Model without re-mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In below scenario, The execution of stored procedure is returning the known columns matching with type "LocalModel"

Is there a way in **EF Core** to query entity and bind that back to anonymous type.

```
List<LocalModel> ModelList= context.Table.FromSql(Stored_Proc +" @Param", _moduleName).ToList();
```

Like, In normal EF this can achieved as below.

```
List<LocalModel> ModelList= context.Database.SqlQuery<LocalModel>("exec Stored_Proc").ToList<LocalModel>();
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between EF Core and "normal" EF examples - both are returning `LocalModel` instances. So what is the issue/question again?

Comment: First query is to show what I was trying in Core, that do not work in EF Core

Answer (score 1):

If you use `FromSql` on the `DbSet` of the type you want to bind to, then it will create instances of that POCO class. For example:

Assuming:

```
public DbSet<LocalModel> LocalModels { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
context.LocalModels.FromSql(...).ToList();
```

If you're working generically, or just if you prefer, you can use `Set<T>()` instead of the actual `DbSet` property name:

```
context.Set<LocalModel>().FromSql(...).ToList();
```